# updating data from indicator during premarket instead of beginning of session possible?

Tags: pine-script

I wrote a script to draw yesterday's high/low/close and high/low from 2 days ago.

I'd like the script to update the lines during the premarket of the current day instead of the beginning of the session at 9h30.

Is there a simple way to do this or that would involve rewriting the whole script in a more complicated way (I'm new to pine script)?

```
//@version=4
study("YY H/L2", overlay=true)
security_1 = security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', high[1], lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)
plot(timeframe.isintraday ? security_1 : na, title="Yhigh", trackprice=true, offset=-99999, color=#a5d6a7, linewidth=2)
security_2 = security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', low[1], lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)
plot(timeframe.isintraday ? security_2 : na, title="Ylow", trackprice=true, offset=-99999, color=#4caf50, linewidth=2)
security_3 = security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', high[2], lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)
plot(timeframe.isintraday ? security_3 : na, title="YYhigh", trackprice=true, offset=-99999, color=#ffcc80, linewidth=2)
security_4 = security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', low[2], lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)
plot(timeframe.isintraday ? security_4 : na, title="YYlow", trackprice=true, offset=-99999, color=#ff9800, linewidth=2)
security_5 = security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', close[1], lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)
plot(timeframe.isintraday ? security_5 : na, title="Yclose", trackprice=true, offset=-99999, color=#b39ddb, linewidth=2)
```

UPDATE:
I'm trying to add a second variable that would update the lines on the chart at the end of the daily session at 16:00

```
security_1 = security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', high[1], lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)  
security_1a = security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', high, lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)
```

Would that be possible to use `security_1` between 9h30 and 15h59 and `security_1a` between 16h00 and 9h29 the next day in the `plot()` function? That way, as soon the as the session ends (and afterhours start), the line would be updated to the high of the current day. Like this, when the chart is opened during premarket the next day, the lines are already at what will be "yesterday's high" before the session begins.

I was thinking using an if statement for this but what I've tried until now didn't work.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem? I'm trying to accomplish the same thing

Answer (score 0):

Pre-market data isn't available from the daily intervals seen by `security()`.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned Luc, pre- and post- markets aren't parts of the daily session, so to achive them, you should call in security not the `'D'`-timeframe, but `'1440'` instead:

```
security_1 = security(syminfo.tickerid, '1440', high[1], lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)
```

And of course that script must be called on intraday resolution with turned on the extended session on the chart.

Comment: Thx Michel! Didn't know that.

Comment: @Michel_T. Thanks for the reply, although I need to keep using the daily 'D' timeframe to track the highs and lows. By calling '1440', the script is taking into account the highs and lows from the extended session which I don't want. What I'd like is to update the horizontal lines at market closes to reflect the session that just ended. I edited my initial post with what I tried.

Comment: But pre and post markets are parts of the extended session. You might keep the daily-resoluton on the chart, but build a new tickerid via the function tickerid and set there extended session. So you can request the data in security.